# Creating a new HTML or PHP page for each post

Tags: javascript, php, html

Basically I am looking for some direction first if its possible and second where to look.  I have done some research on this site and others but havent found exactly what im thinking about.

Example:
I have a main page www.xxx.com where you can post a story and its a news feed similar to fb listing all stories in date order.  I want to be able to create an entirely new html or php page dynamically each time the user posts a story.  For example.  www.xxx.com/36.html then someone makes another post and upon submission it makes a page www.xxx.com/37.html. On the main page it looks the same to the user but on the back end file structure its creating a new page for each post.  Is this possible and where to look?

Comment: I would look into how WordPress or another application works. Typically an application like this would not write out files for each page. All requests would be routed to the application which would then generate HTML from data stored in a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you store the stories in a database, then make a handler to present the stories.

Id store the stories in a database, give the stories UID's then use query strings to present the right page to the user.

take a look at $_SERVER
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

use $_SERVER to access the query string of the requested URL

then make a call to the database base depending on what id is in the query string.

for example:

1. The requested URL : www.xxx.com/stories?id=22
2. get the id from the query string
3. Make a call to the database for unique id 22
4. Display data.

This will take up less space on your server also as you will not be storing duplicate HTML for ever page

**Answer2 How to dynamically change meta tags**

You will need to create a separate html file that will be used to display the stories.

Make sure the head of that file looks something like this:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
[@storyMeta]
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript">
</head>
```

In the php handler script you are creating to dynamically display the stories add this code.

```
// get this from database relate the tag to story ID
$metaTag = '<meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript">'; 

//get contents of the html file
$html = file_get_contents('/path/tp/html/template');
//replace the string with the meta tag
$html = str_replace("[@storyMeta]", $metaTag, $html);

//display the page to the user
echo $html;
```

this means you will only have 1 bit of html you can re-use you will have no duplicate html code (like you would if you created a page for each story). This also means if you need to change the HTML (change layout or something) you will only have to edit 1 file to modify every story page.

Please let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: this is exactly what im doing right now.  The problem is sharing the stories to facebook because it acts as one page and the Meta tags don't share the correct previews.  So I figured I needed entirely new pages for each post. Thoughts? Is there a way to dynamically change the meta tags for og?

Comment: You can use string replace to switch out meta tags. For example, create a HTML page which you can require into the handel script. in the html page, between the head tags, write something like [@pageMeta] (use a string that will not be used in a story) in the handel you can then use string replace  to replace the string [@pageMeta] with the meta tag you need. (store the meta tag in the DB and make sure its related to the correct UID for the story. Hope that helps, happy to answer anymore questions

Comment: I know you were already coding what i suggested before i posted, but if the suggestion about dynamically changing meta tags helps would be great if you could accept the answer :) trying to build that rep a little. also happy to carry on helping if you have any more questions

Comment: Sure will accept it as the answer if you can give me an example of how to use string replace to switch out the meta tags.

Comment: No problem, ill get together an example now

Comment: how would you like me to post to code? edit my first answer or create a new one ?

Comment: Edit your first answer, thats fine.

Comment: Please not this is the basic concept. you will need to do things like check if the file exists before reading etc. I use this concept in a tempting system i built and it works very well ( my code is much different to this as im using OOP). You can also use this technique to dynamically change the story

Comment: Thanks Jay.  I will accept this answer.

Comment: No problem, any time. if you have any more questions please ask, happy to help where I can. thanks for accepting

Answer (score -3):

Use php's fwrite and create a html document
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php

Comment: Storing all posts of a blofg on different files is a terrible idea. What if you want to change some text in the header? It would be painful. Databases should be used instead.

Comment: Im not saying its best, I would never do it this way. Im simply answering the question that was asked. If you wanted to create a html page on the server fwrite can do it, whether it is good practice is a totally different question

Comment: Stack Overflow is not about 'asking the question that was asked'. You should be more concerned if other people viewing this question will benefit from it, and not only the question author.

Comment: And what about the case of when you DO want to create an html page? I used fwrite with a templating engine to dynamically build standard static sites for a company when they added a client to thier database to ease the workflow where the staff didn't have the skillset, they are still using it and it still works great for them